# Update only part of an Android notification with custom layout

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have created an Android status bar notification with a custom layout which contains a button and a textview (im using ICS api). 
When the button is pressed, it sends a pendingintent to a broadcast receiver. When the receiver receives the intent, I want it to update the textview in the notification. Is this possible without recreating an entirely new notification and passing the same ID?

In the broadcast receiver there is an error creating the pendingintent "The method getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (lereceiver, int, Intent, int)" 
The same code works in the activity that created the notification

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is this textview, in your custom layout, and is this after the user selected the notification?

Comment: the textview is in the custom layout of the notification. I solved this problem by using notification.builder and passing only the part that i want to modify. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the updated notification with the same notification id